# How to prevent css selector from access into iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe.

I want to prevent access from the parent document into the iframe from css selectors and other manipulation.

How can I secure it?

Comment: CSS doesn’t cross document boundaries.

Comment: Just remove <link> tag you forget inside iframe.html

Answer (score 1):

You could kill a goat under the light of a full moon inside a pentagram made of salt. If you did that, css or js wouldn't be able to affect the contents of an iframe.

They wouldn't affect them if you didn't either.

You have to explicitly allow sites to interact with the contents of an iframe, either by setting up an api [like this](https://medium.com/@Farzad_YZ/cross-domain-iframe-parent-communication-403912fff692), or by setting up cors headers to allow interaction. According to other answers on this site, if the iframe and parent have the same domain, cors rules don't apply, so changes can be made. If you are embedding an iframe from your site on your site, you should probably trust your own code.

If you are asking how to prevent users from using the developer tools to mess around with your iframe contents, you can't. There are all sorts of things that website designers have tried to do to keep me from looking at their source. I've never found one that can keep me out.

Comment: my question is in reference more toward the later of users opening up dev tools. but to be specific, we have some bot that's crawling our site, selecting the links for the ads on the page, and going to the links; this is causing us to receive penalties. i'm fine with users being able to see the code; i just don't want bots to be able to select the code through css selectors. is this possible?